Question about Neukirch ANT Proposition $4.2$
A subgroup $\Gamma\subset V$ is a lattice if and only if it is discrete.
The proof is on page 25 there are few non trivial lines for me

As the $\mu_i= \gamma_i- \gamma_{0i}\in \Gamma$

Why $\mu_i $ is in $\Gamma$ , it can be an interior point of mesh.
And why the intersection is compact and discrete.


$\mu_i$ is the difference of two elements of $\Gamma$, hence in $\Gamma$

the intersection is a subspace of a discrete space (, namely $\Gamma$), hence discrete. It is also closed and bounded by construction, hence compact.

Make your question more self-contained, so the reader does not have to have Neukirch with them.  Specifically, your question does not include a definition of a lattice. Some number theory books would not consider $\mathbf Z(1,0)$ to be a lattice in $\mathbf R^2$ but it is discrete.

A subgroup $ \Gamma \subset V $ is a lattice if and only if it is discrete. A lattice is a vector space $ V $ is a subgroup $ \Gamma $ such that: $ \Gamma $ is discrete. The quotient space $ V / \Gamma $ is compact.
In your particular question, why
$$ \mu_{i} = \gamma_{i} - \gamma_{0i} \in \Gamma $$
$$ \mu_{i} = \gamma_{i} - \gamma_{0i} $$
for $ \gamma_i, \gamma_{0i} \in \Gamma $. This is true because $ \Gamma $ is a group, and the difference between two elements of a group is also an element of the same group. Therefore, $ \mu_{i} \in \Gamma $.
Givern that $ \Gamma $ is discrete, for $ V / \Gamma $ to be compact, we must show that there's boundedness and that the quotient space respects the topology. It should follow that $ V / \Gamma $ forms a tiling of $ V $ such that each coset corresponds to a distinct point in $ \Gamma $.
Because $ \Gamma $ is discrete, it means that there's a neighborhood around each element of $ V $ that does not contain any other points of $ \Gamma $. This ensures that translating by elements of $ \Gamma $ does not interfere with compactness and maintain discreteness.
I know I sound like a broken record but given $ \Gamma $ is discrete, each $ \mu_i $ defined as $ \gamma_i - \gamma_{0i} \in \Gamma $ due to group properties. Consequently, the intersect in $ V/\Gamma $ remains compact and discrete due to the nature of lattices in vector spaces.

If this makes no grammatical sense i will edit post when i wake up

You can probably answer my other questions on the same topic.
